# Git GUI - how fixed issue Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, user-interface

I hava issue about pull from git GUI, how i can do fixed this issue "
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
" 
 [screenshot issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEtAD.png)

Comment: Did you try to clone in command line?

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate SSH public key
   https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key
2. In web interface of your git server (bitbucket, gitlab, github, ...) find your account settings. There you can add your public ssh-key
3. Try to clone your repo in command line, i.e.:

   git clone git@bitbucket.org:your_user/your_repo.git

From now you can git clone/push/... without enter your password

Comment: this didn't help in my case, as everything seems to be working fine on the mingw TERMINAL interface... it's only GIT GUI that seems to be having an issue using my key. It seems like it's some sort of environment variable or command line argument issue, since it only happens if I right-click and choose "GIT GUI here". If, instead, I choose "GIT Bash", then type git-gui, it works fine as if the shell passed it my
key as a parameter or something.

Comment: Hi @TwistedCode Have you got this issue resolved. I have the exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> [...]everything seems to be working fine on the mingw TERMINAL
> interface... it's only GIT GUI that seems to be having an issue using
> my key[...]  it only happens if I right-click and  choose "GIT GUI
> here". If, instead, I choose "GIT Bash", then type git-gui, it works
> fine[...]

From your comment I get that you were running windows and only have problems with Git GUI started from explorer. I had the same issue (in 2022).

Git GUI will look in your `C:\Users\<User>\.ssh` folder for a `config` file. If you add a `config` file (no extension) you can add the paths of your keys. Otherwise git GUI will only look for default key names.
For some reason Git GUI doesn't execute `~/.profile` or  `~/.bashrc` (Git Bash does), which can be used to autostart ssh agent and add keys.

This type of config file worked for me:

```
IdentitiesOnly=yes
PreferredAuthentications publickey
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\id_ed25519_your_key
IdentityFile /c/Users/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519_your_key
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_your_key
```

Any of the three path notations work. See https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config for syntax of the config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows:

1. Open git bash and navigate to /.ssh directory using following command

> cd ~/.ssh

2. This folder contains your public key inside **id_rsa.pub** file
3. Open this file and copy all it's content (your public key)

> cat id_rsa.pub

4. Now open your GitHub settings and add new SSH key
   https://github.com/settings/keys
5. You should be able to push changes now.